# Regex for special characters

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to write regex to check for special characters in a text paragraph (including 'script' and 'javascript' keyword) using:

```
"(script)|(javascript)|([/'()&<>^~`|\"])"
```

But this doesn't work if I mix letters with it. Let's say if I enter `<` , it will detect but if I enter `<s` ir will not detect.

Comment: Has nothing to do with Spring, removed spring tag.

Comment: You're regex looks for strings that consist of exactly one of the special characters (or matches the first two patterns).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
".*(script|javascript|[/'()&<>^~`|\"]).*"
```

I added a `.*` before and after the regex.

Which means:

- zero or more of any character
- followed by any of the special characters (or patterns)
- followed by zero or more of any character

This should allow your regex to match patterns like this:

```
aaaa<
aaaa<a
<aaaaa
<
xscript
scriptx
xxscriptxx
```

---

Here's another way to do it:

```
static final Pattern INVALID_CHARS = Pattern.compile("[/'()&<>^~`|\"]");

boolean isInvalid(String s) {
    if (s.indexOf("javascript") != -1) {
        return true;
    }
    if (s.indexOf("script") != -1) {
        return true;
    }
    if (INVALID_CHARS.matcher(s).find()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It won't detect '<s' because it's not designed to.

All that's going to do is match either one instance of "javascript", one instance of "script" or exactly one of those special characters.

If you want it to detect '<s; you need to use a * or +... something like

```
((script)|(javascript)|([/'()&<>^~`|\"]))+
```

Although that wont match '<s', it will match '<script'

Comment: As of now it works only for single character. If type any text let's say "This is the  | first text". This (|) not getting  detected.
Same way if I type 'script', it will get detected but if I type "This is a script" it is not getting detected